# Google collab is stuck on download from hugging face

Tags: google-colaboratory

Trying to download a model/dataset from hugging face is stuck at the download step and does not proceed forever. Looking at logs does not help. I tried creating different notebooks and iam still facing with the same error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around I found that it is a error with hugging face hub and  the latest version of hugging face hub should fix this. If you are getting this error run the below command at the top of your notebook.

!pip install -U huggingface_hub